# Library can't find libgomp.1.dylib despite it's being present

Tags: gcc, cmake, macports

I'm trying to build OpenSfM on my M1 MacBook. I installed GCC11, Ceres and OpenCV via MacPorts. I needed to add `/opt/local/lib` manually to OpenSfM's `CMakeLists.txt` as setuptools somehow didn't find ceres.h, but afterwards compiling OpenSfM worked fine.

When I later on run a program that uses OpenSfM, it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pvitt/projects/odm/./run.py", line 19, in <module>
    from stages.odm_app import ODMApp
  File "/Users/pvitt/projects/odm/stages/odm_app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from stages.run_opensfm import ODMOpenSfMStage
  File "/Users/pvitt/projects/odm/stages/run_opensfm.py", line 14, in <module>
    from opendm.osfm import OSFMContext
  File "/Users/pvitt/projects/odm/opendm/osfm.py", line 14, in <module>
    from opensfm.large import metadataset
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensfm-0.5.2-py3.9.egg/opensfm/large/metadataset.py", line 7, in <module>
    from opensfm import io
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensfm-0.5.2-py3.9.egg/opensfm/io.py", line 11, in <module>
    from opensfm import context, features, geo, pygeometry, pymap, types
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensfm-0.5.2-py3.9.egg/opensfm/features.py", line 9, in <module>
    from opensfm import context, pyfeatures
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensfm-0.5.2-py3.9.egg/opensfm/pyfeatures.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensfm-0.5.2-py3.9.egg/opensfm/pyfeatures.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Having a look into `/opt/local/lib/` shows me that there is a `libgomp.1.dylib`:

```
% ls -al /opt/local/lib/gcc11/libgomp.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  37 May 16 00:57 /opt/local/lib/gcc11/libgomp.1.dylib -> /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgomp.1.dylib
% ls -al /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgomp.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  245120 May 16 00:24 /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgomp.1.dylib
```

[EDIT]
As my CPU architecture is ARM, I need to have the tools and libs also build for this architecture, what they are:

```
% file `which gcc`
/opt/local/bin/gcc: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
% file /opt/local/lib/opencv4/libopencv_core.4.5.2.dylib
/opt/local/lib/opencv4/libopencv_core.4.5.2.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
% file /opt/local/lib/gcc11/libgomp.1.dylib
/opt/local/lib/gcc11/libgomp.1.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

[/EDIT]

So I'm wondering where the error is coming from. Did I do a mistake during compilation? How can I find the reason for this error? As I also had to add `/opt/local/lib` manually to the `CMakeLists.txt` file, I suspect that this path is somehow not published properly. But how comes that a folder where MacPorts puts all it's stuff is not used by cmake? Do I have to publish it manually? Via `CPATH`/`LIBRARY_PATH`? And why can I just use OpenMP:

```
% cat test_omp.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
% gcc -fopenmp test_omp.c
% ./a.out
Hello World... from thread = 1
Hello World... from thread = 3
Hello World... from thread = 2
Hello World... from thread = 5
Hello World... from thread = 4
Hello World... from thread = 6
Hello World... from thread = 0
Hello World... from thread = 7
```

I fear it is something really silly, but I just don't see it.

Comment: M1 needs the libraries for ARM. Are you sure you have installed the right version and that all homebrew packages you are using are prepared for this?

Comment: @usr1234567 I'm not using homebrew, but MacPorts. My GCC and also libgomp is for ARM.